# How to count the number of true values in database where the column contains 'Q1'

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I have a table in an access database which has columns Q1-Easy Q1-Med and Q1-Hard. For a selected username, I need to count the number of columns which contain a true value.

would this SQL statement work? or is there a more elegant way of doing this?

```
string Q1Query = "SELECT COUNT from tbl_Results WHERE ([Q1-Easy] OR [Q1-Med] OR [Q1-Hard] && [Username]) = + selectedUsername + "'";
```

I only know the very basics in SQL and I'm working in C# .NET

Comment: that is a vulnerable sql string for starters.

Comment: Side (but important) note: Use parameterized queries.  Don't build up the SQL with string concatenation.

Comment: AND has precedence over OR, so you'd probably want to group your `([Q1-Easy] OR [Q1-Med] OR [Q1-Hard])` clause into its own parentheses.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you're trying to do.  Your question says "count the number of COLUMNS which contain a true value" but your query is going to return the number of rows that have at least one column with a true value.  Which are you going for?  For example, if the Easy, Med, and Hard columns all have a true value for a given row do you want that counted as 1 or 3?  Pay heed to Woot4Moo's comment as well, even after you get the SQL itself nailed down the approach you are using is dangerous.  Google "SQL Injection"

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I would like it to return a value of 3 if all 3 columns have a true value for that user. Or two if only 2 are true. I'm not looking for rows, it should be columns. thanks, L

Comment: Ah, nuts.  My answer isn't going to help with adding up the number of trues.  But do take a look at the query parameterization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if you want to count the number of true columns you're going to need something like the following.  Note that I'm assuming a 'Y' value means true... if you are using bit columns you'll have to make slight changes.  I'm also assuming you're on SQL Server, if that is not the case this syntax may not work for you.

```
   SELECT 
      CASE Q1-Easy WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
      CASE Q1-Med  WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
      CASE Q1-Hard WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TrueCount
   FROM tbl_Results
   WHERE ([Username] = @username)
```

For MS Access, it would be something like the following (untested)...

```
   SELECT 
      IIF([Q1-Easy] = 'Y', 1, 0) + 
      IIF([Q1-Med] = 'Y', 1, 0) +
      IIF([Q1-Hard] = 'Y', 1, 0) AS TrueCount
   FROM tbl_Results
   WHERE ([Username] = @username)
```

Comment: Aha!  I had a mental block on `CASE`.  Your answer gives the query he needs, mine provides a safe way to add the parameterization.

Comment: thank you dazedandconfused, this is exactly what I'm trying to do but it is with an access database

Comment: Edited to add MS Access syntax.  I don't have Access available at the moment so it might need a little tweak but should get you in the ballpark.

Comment: thank you so much dazedandconfused - this has worked for me exactly the way you show here! Totally appreciate the fast and helpful responses from stack overflow members, its a great site. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Your query isn't too far off the mark.   What you'd want is

```
string Q1Query = "SELECT COUNT(*) from tbl_Results WHERE ([Q1-Easy] = 'Y' OR [Q1-Med] = 'Y' OR [Q1-Hard] = 'Y') && [Username] = '" + selectedUsername + "'";
```

(Assuming your "true value" is 'Y'.)

That being said, embedding your SQL in C# and building it up via string concatenation is a bad idea. It allows the possibility of malicious inputs such as `selectedUsername` containing the value `"Bobby'; DROP TABLE Students"`. A much better practice is to parameterize the query and let the database code put in the username or better yet, put the entire query into a stored procedure.

To avoid the SQL injection vulnernability, you'd want to change the query to something like this:

```
string Q1Query = "SELECT COUNT(*) from tbl_Results WHERE ([Q1-Easy] = 'Y' OR [Q1-Med] = 'Y' OR [Q1-Hard] = 'Y') && [Username] = '@username'";
```

(Note the removal of the concatenation for the username.)

And then you'd actually run it with something like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Q1Query);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", selectedUsername);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: got this code working with a MS Access database using: Con.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = selectedStudent;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    int result = ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                    string resultString = result.ToString();
                    MessageBox.Show(resultString);
                    Con.Close();   Then realised I got the answer 1 when I should have been getting 3. It's the columns I want to count instead of the rows. The CASE statement does what I want but I'm using MS Access

Comment: After your comment with the clarification about needing the number of columns, I realized my query wasn't going to work.  The answer from @dazedandconfused is the way to go.  But either way, you should absolutely avoid building SQL queries in middle tier code.  Parameterized is **much** safer.

Answer (score 0):

The parentheses are wrong in the query.  This is the form at that you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
from tbl_Results
WHERE ([Q1-Easy] = 'TRUE' OR [Q1-Med] = 'TRUE' OR [Q1-Hard] = 'TRUE') AND
      ([Username] = + selectedUsername)
```

I'm not sure how "true" is represented in your data, so the value might be different.

Answer (score 0):

Almost the same as yours by with minor yet important corrections:

```
string Q1Query = "SELECT [UserName], COUNT(*) as ToTalTrueQuestions 
FROM tbl_Results WHERE ([Q1-Easy] OR [Q1-Med] OR [Q1-Hard]) 
AND [Username] = '" +    selectedUsername + "'";
```

The difference first is I include the name of the user to associate with the count, second the count has an alias, third your use of parenthesis is wrong I put the closing parenthesis "`)`" after the [Q1-Hard] not after [Username], fourth I use `AND` which is for SQL instead of `&&` which is for C# and finally there is a single quote after `"="`, that is `"= '"` should be the correct one.